# Is Deadpool's anatomy the same as a normal humans?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2

Obviously, Deadpool has the same anatomy when it come to morphology; he has the same amount of hands, legs, he has 1 head, etc. But is the rest of his anatomy the same as a humans? Does he have a jugular vein, for example? Does he have all 206 bones in the same spot? Wolverine has Adamantium bones, but I don't think Deadpool does, so his bones would be made of the same material as a humans. Deadpool also doesn't have claws like Wolverine, so would he have the same hand structure? Deadpools suit is red because he bleeds. Please keep in mind that I am not talking about the version of Deadpool where he has all of the X-mens powers. I am talking about the revised timeline in the new X-men movies and the Deadpool Killogy series. Basically, in these versions of Deadpool,

**If a surgeon did an anatomy dissection of Deadpool, would his anatomy be the same as a human's body, in terms of structure and organs/ blood vessels, bones, etc?**

Comment: So, not MCU (where he hasn't appeared yet) or X-Men movies where he hasn't appeared, other than as Project X in *Wolverine*, but not in his own movies either?

Comment: @ZeissIkon I mean the revised timeline in the x men movies and in the Deadpool Killogy series in the comics.

Comment: Comics and X-Men movies may disagree...

Comment: @ZeissIkon that is why I discounted the original timeline where he had every power.

Comment: You couldn't do an anatomical dissection. He'd heal faster than you could cut

Comment: https://www.syfy.com/syfy-wire/marvel-anatomy-a-scientific-study-of-the-superhuman-exclusive-first-look

Comment: @Valorum if you rip him in half you can. I was not asking specifically about a dissection, but whether or not Deadpool's insides were the same as ours. Based on Fuzzyboot's answer, I think they are. Even though he has more durability, he can still be injured, feel pain, etc. (otherwise there would be no need for the healing factor, and it would never be shown).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comics, Deadpool has not been shown to have anything but human physiology. He has had multiple organs removed, including his heart, and he's had his guts on display several times, and they've always appeared human. As regards bones, indeed, his bones are not reinforced, and in a few comics, he's had himself put onto a rack, and had his bones rebroken, because they healed crooked.

So, in short, he essentially has an entirely human body, other than that it heals rapidly, including from things that would normally completely kill even a regenerator such as decapitation and being reduced to ash. It's worth noting that comics Deadpool's healing factor was initially the result of having Wolverine's healing factor copied over to him, but that he was later cursed by Thanos to be unable to die (in part because he learned Deadpool had been flirting with Death, Thanos's crush, during his near-death experiences) and Thanos is one of the few people who can kill Deadpool permanently, but removing that curse (which he did, although he restored Deadpool's curse after this resulted in Death going AWOL).

Comment: Is this specific to the Killogy series?  Otherwise, possibly Not An Answer...

Comment: @ZeissIkon As long as what is true in the comics is the same as the Killogy comics series, it is answer, but from this answer, Deadpool has a anatomy just like you or me, the only potential caveat is whether the killogy is different.

Comment: FuzzyBoots so Deadpool's body/physiology is the same as you or me, right? btw, do you know if there are any exceptions to this in the killogy series? If not, then this answer is perfect.

Comment: @Guy: As far as I know, the "Killogy" collection used his traditional powers which were basically just rapid regeneration, cancer, and insanity. Unless you're perhaps tapping into the "Deadpool Corps" section where they have all of the alternate versions of Deadpool?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots no, I wasn't talking about the alternate Deadpool's I was talking about the one who killed the Marvel Universe. So would my anatomy be the same as Deadpool's then? I think that would be cool :  ).

Comment: Well, except that what's ripped off doesn't grow back...  ;)

Comment: @ZeissIkon I meant except for the healing factor. But both we and Deadpool can have parts ripped off...

Comment: Yes. Deadpool essentially has regular human anatomy other than the healing factor and the cancer.

Comment: Ok, thanks! btw, some regular humans also have cancer.

Comment: @Guy: Yes, but it's been established several times in the comics that Wade's version is special in that it's tied into his healing factor. Without the healing factor, the cancer is supercharged and kills rapidly. Without the cancer, the healing factor causes uncontrolled growth, as a bunch of Skrulls learned when they tried to borrow it from him.

Comment: @Fuzzyboots Ok, that makes sense now. I'm sorry that I thought the cancer was just normal cancer, I didn't read all of the comics : (

Comment: No worries. It might be normal in the Fox (now MCU) version. It's left ambiguous.